# trouble geting started with laravel testing and mockery

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to get started on unit testing with laravel and am trying to follow a couple of tutorials.

Alot of my controllers have been generated using Jeffrey Ways excellent generators and they appear to create their own tests so I thought it would be simple to get started.

I've installed mockery and sqlite - I've removed a lot of the tests from the folder for now so I can test one at a time but I'm having trouble with the first one that tests a create:

Here's my test:

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;
use Way\Tests\Factory;

class BooksTest extends TestCase {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mock = m::mock('Eloquent', 'Book');
        $this->collection = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')->shouldDeferMissing();
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->attributes = Factory::book(['id' => 1]);
        $this->app->instance('Book', $this->mock);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn($this->collection);
        $this->call('GET', 'books');

        $this->assertViewHas('books');
    }

    public function testCreate()
    {
        $this->call('GET', 'books/create');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    public function testStore()
    {
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('create')->once();
        $this->validate(true);
        $this->call('POST', 'books');

        $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('books.index');
    }

}
```

When I run phpunit I get lots of php messages around mockery - theres so much there I cant see the specifc error message

Is there a simple step I'm missing here in my set up??

I've added mockery to my composer.json and updated. I have not added anything to app.php in the config files - package didnt suggest I should or as a facade.

So I'm not sure, never having used it before whether mockery is installed correctly - although I assume it is. Was it necessary for me to add mockery to a laravel installation or is it part of a normal install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - definite PICNIC error

I needed to extend the buffer size of my command line to scroll back and see the error which identified the problem - 
This is my first dip into testing so didnt quite expect the fail to go the way it did.

Tiny steps required